# Impulse period measurement using NUCLEO-F401RE board and input capture mode

Tags: stm32, timer, counter

I have an encoder sensor, which produces high and low levels. I want to capture the period (or frequency) of these levels using NUCLEO-F401RE board and input capture mode for TIM1. I don't want to use interrupt and two TIM1 channels, and don't want to put extra load on cpu so I am searching for hardware based solution. I was thinking to reset Timer counter value to 0 every time impulse comes and current value is registered. This way I will always start at 0 and get counter value when impulse comes. But I don't know if this is possible on STM32 platform so tried googling it and found that Clear-on-capture should do just that, the only problem is that I can't find anywhere on CubeMX how to enable this feature. Is there any other way, to reset Timer counter value after it has been read by input capture mode ?

Comment: ST calls this "PWM Input", see subchapter with this name in TIM chapter in Reference Manual. I don't use CubeMX but I guess it will be there under "PWM Input" too.